# How do I target all nodes in a container after a specified element?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to target all elements after `$(".item:eq(1)")` that are within the `<ul class="items">` This should include `<li class="category">` then add them to `<ul class="items-2">`

original tree:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li class="category">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item">item 1</li>
      <li class="item">item 2</li>
      <li class="item">item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item">item 4</li>
      <li class="item">item 5</li>
      <li class="item">item 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="items-2></ul>
```

*aditional info*

Ultimately I'm trying to limit a `<ul class="items>` to `x` items. If the column has more than `x` I want it to move it to the next `<ul class="items-2">`

i'm seeing this is more complicated than I originally was thinking but here is the expected tree:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li class="category">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item">item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="items-2>
  <li class="category">
    <ul>
      <li class="item">item 2</li>
      <li class="item">item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="item">item 4</li>
      <li class="item">item 5</li>
      <li class="item">item 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I had already tried that but nextAll() doesn't seem to grab the next .item and the next .category I want to grab all the nodes below the 2nd .item

Comment: So you want to have items 3, 4, 5 and 6 in your set if I understand correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: what does expected result tree look like?

Comment: made some edits to my post after thinking it through...seems quite a bit more complicated than I originally was thinking in my head.

Comment: Wait, so your goal is to have each sequential ul have one more item then the previous ul?

Comment: no. say I have 12 items total. I want to only have 8 items in the first ul(column) and then push the rest of the items past 8 into the next ul(column). i'm realizing this might be the best way approach my problem. I probably will have to change the html the template spits out to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can `splice` a jQuery object like a regular array:

```
var all = $('.item');
var thirdOnwards = all.splice(2);
$('.items-2').append(thirdOnwards);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rvM8q/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `splice` for some reason, here's an alternative:

```
var ignoreUntil = $(".item:eq(1)")[0];
var result = $(".item").filter(function() {
    if (this == ignoreUntil) {
        ignoreUntil = null;
        return false;
    }

    return !ignoreUntil;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gt` function in your selector like:

```
$(".item:gt(1)")
```

Then, you can proceed to append with jQuery each:

```
$(".item:gt(1)").each(function(){

    $('.items-2').append($(this).clone());
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNBS9/)

Updated fiddle to OPs change in requirements:
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNBS9/1/)

Comment: close. I think i've led people astray here and the issue is more complicated than I was hoping for. I can't have items that were under title 1 end up under title 2. The expected tree shows what I would hope for. I'm currently working on trying a different initial tree to help this.

Comment: Ok well let me know if you still need help after you have your new tree